# return null when List<Object> is empty error: [return.type.incompatible]

Tags: java, list, object, arraylist, collections

I am trying to return null when List is empty:

```
public List<Object> extractOutput(List<Object> accumulator) {
  if (accumulator.isEmpty()){
    return null;
  }
  return accumulator;
}
```

But I am getting error: [return.type.incompatible].
I would really appreciate if I get fix to the problem.

Comment: It is considered bad practice to return `null` when you could instead return `emptyList()` and save the caller from having to do null checks.

Comment: I suppose the method `extractOutput()` overrides an `extractOutput()` method in a super class with a wrong return type.

Answer (score 0):

Returning null is considered as a **bad practice**. It would be a much **better solution** if your method `extractOutput()` returns an empty list **instead** of `null`.

Solution:

```
public List<Object> extractOutput(List<Object> accumulator) {
  if (accumulator.isEmpty()){
    return Collections.emptyList();
  }
  return accumulator;
}
```

I hope I could help you, keep your great work up!